# MVVM OnpropertyChange UI changes delayed

Tags: wpf, mvvm

i have a comboxbox that while it is beign populated i want it replaced in the UI by a message saying it is being loaded.
i did this by using a textbox showing the message and giving both objects visibility bindings in the view model (IsShowAuthComboBox &LoadingAuthenticationMsg)

here's the XAML code

```
<ComboBox x:Name="ComboBoxAuthSource"
    Grid.Row="3"
    Style="{StaticResource ComboBoxStyle}"
    SelectedItem ="{Binding SelectedAuthenticationSource,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
    ItemsSource="{Binding AuthenticationSource,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"  
    Visibility= "{Binding IsShowAuthComboBox, Converter={StaticResource BoolToVis}}" />

<TextBox x:Name="ComboBoxAuthCover"
    Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="{StaticResource TableColumn}"
    Style="{StaticResource  FieldBoxStyle }"
    FontSize="12"
    IsReadOnly="True"
    Visibility="{Binding IsShowGettingAuthenticationMsg, Converter={StaticResource BoolToVis}}"
    Text="{Binding LoadingAuthenticationMsg,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged,Mode=OneWay,FallbackValue='Loading authentication sources...'}" />
```

And here's the viewModel

```
public bool IsShowAuthComboBox
    {
        set
        {
            if (_isShowAuthenticationComboBox != value)
            {                   
                _isShowAuthenticationComboBox = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("IsShowAuthComboBox");
                OnPropertyChanged("IsShowGettingAuthenticationMsg");
            }              
        }
        get =>_isShowAuthenticationComboBox; 
    }

public bool IsShowGettingAuthenticationMsg => !_isShowAuthenticationComboBox;


 public virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
        {
            Log.Write(LogClass.General, LogLevel.Debug,
                $"{propertyName} update triggerd",
                _moduleName);
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
```

this code is the first thing that happens in  the relevant flow, but i will sometimes only see it at the very end of the execution and for only for an instant.
at other times it will work as expected.

what am i missing here?

EDIT : 
this also accurs when validating the IP ,simpler code.
here's the code

```
 public string SelectedServer
        {
            get => _selectedServer;
            set
            {
                lock (_lockObj)
                {               
                    IsShowAuthComboBox = false;
                    if (!IsValideIp(value))

                    //some code
                    IsShowAuthComboBox  = true;
                }
            }

bool IsValideIp(string ip)
{
   //some code

  //calls the server sync
   return RemotingConfigurator.GetServerConfig(ip).isValid;
}
```

Comment: What does "while it is being populated" mean here? Are you loading some items from a database or similar?

Comment: @mm8 , yes, AuthenticationSource is an  ObservableCollection<string> that is populated via database. it takes about 5 seconds.

Comment: Show your code then. You should call the database on a background thread.

Comment: what difference does it make?
Onpropertychanges() calls that take place before calling the server have no effect.

Comment: The same thread cannot both update the UI and query the database at the same time.

Comment: added relevant code

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/182942/discussion-between-danw25-and-mm8).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is what i ended up doing. moved the UI changes away from the data layer and into the viewModel (SetUiOnWait)

```
public string SelectedServer
        {
            get => _selectedServer;


    set
        {
            //IsShowAuthComboBox = false;
            SetUiOnWait(true);

            Log.Write(LogClass.General, LogLevel.Debug,
                $"Server changed from {_selectedServer} to {value} by user",
                _moduleName);

            _selectedServer = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
            // OnPropertyChanged();

            //workaround for when changing servers when a unique  
            //authentication source is selected causes the selected source to be null :\
            if (AuthenticationSource.Any())
            {
                SelectedAuthenticationSource = AuthenticationSource[0];
            }

            Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
            {
                LoginInfo.SelectedServer = _selectedServer;

            }).ContinueWith((t) =>
            {
                if(t.Exception !=null)
                {
                    ExceptionLog.Write(t.Exception.GetBaseException(),_moduleName);
                }
                RefreshAuthenticationProperties();
                OnPropertyChanged("IsLimitedClinicalUse");
                OnPropertyChanged("IsNotForClinicalUse");
                SetUiOnWait(false);
            });
        }

 public void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
{
    dispatcher.Invoke((Action)(() =>
               {
                   //PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));                          
               }));
}
```

Task.Factory.StartNew() forces and logic to be executed on a new thread and for the UI changes to wait for it be completed.

and invoke within OnPropertyChange forces the event to be handled by the  UI thread.

Answer (score 1):

Your issue is that you are setting the `IsShowAuthComboBox` property and calling the `IsValideIp` synchronously on the same thread. And a single thread cannot both update the UI and query a database simultaneously.

What you should do is to call the `IsValideIp` on a background thread. I wouldn't do this in the setter of a property though, but rather in a command. You may want to read [@Stephen Cleary's blog post](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/01/async-oop-3-properties.html) on the subject.

Comment: tried calling it via a new task, but issue still persists.
i don't understand why the UI does not change as soon as the onPropertyChanged event is raised .

Comment: Because it's blocked by the call to the IsValideIp method.